# How to get the second argument from route in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get the second argument from the route in laravel from the following code.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('users/{name}/forksnippets/{name2}','Forksnippet@viewforksnippet');
```

**controller**

```
public function viewforksnippet($slug){
    dd($slug);
}
```

getting name here as result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the second argument to the method of the controller.

```php
public function viewforksnippet($slug, $name2)
{
    dd($slug, $name2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function viewforksnippet($name, $name2)
{
    dd($name2);
}
```

Please try this ex